# How to solve a differential equation with a non-constant coefficient using Python ？

Tags: python, scipy, ode, differential-equations

Suppose there is an equation about the length of the bungee cord (denoted by x), which is dependent on the mass of the object e.g. a player (denoted by m).

Assume that the natural length of the bungee cord is 30 meters, in other words, the starting position is x(0)=-30.

The equation of the length of the bungee cord is given by:

```
    x''(m) = g + b/m*x(m) -a1/m*x'(m) - a2*|x'(m)|*x'(m)
```

where `g, a1, a2` are constants; `b` is a step function: `b = -k` (another constant) when `x<0` and `b = 0` when `x>=0`.

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

g = 9.8
a1, a2 = 0.6, 0.8
k = 20
b = [-k, 0]

def dx_dt(x, m):
    if x[0]>=0:
        return [x[1], g+b[0]/m*x[0]-a1/m*x[1]-a2/m*np.abs(x[1])*x[1]]
    else:
        return [x[1], g+b[1]/m*x[0]-a1/m*x[1]-a2/m*np.abs(x[1])*x[1]]

init = [[-30, 0], [-40, 0.0001]]

m = np.linspace(1, 100, 10000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, figsize=(6, 4))

for i in range(len(init)):
    xs = odeint(dx_dt, init[i], m)
    ax[i].plot(m, xs[:, 0], 'r-')
    ax[i].set_xlabel('mass (m)')
    ax[i].set_ylabel('length (x)')
    ax[i].set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
    ax[i].set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
    ax[i].set_title('init={}'.format(init[i]))
```

the right answer should be a sine-like curve

but the result from above codes turns out to be

[image]

Is there something wrong with the codes?

Comment: Your plot appears to be a phase-space plot, i.e. you did something like `plot(xs[:, 0], xs[:, 1])`.  Did you mean to plot the solution as a function of time?  E.g. use `plot(m, xs[:, 0])` to plot the first component of the solution as a function of time.

Comment: It certainly does look quite sinusoidal if you look at it right

Comment: It is quite unusual to have the mass also as the time. Everything else looks quite physical, is this parameter coincidence intentional?

Comment: At the moment you simulate a jumper that has mass 1 kg at time 1 sec and increases steadily in gaining mass to 100 kg at time 100 sec. Is that realistic? And see the first comment, you label (m,x), but you plot (x,x').

Comment: Sorry, I found that I omitted parts of the codes... This time I show the complete one and some background detail is added. My teacher said my plot was not right, but I have no idea where is the fault because I am a novice in system dynamics.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you for pointing this out. Yeah, I chose the wrong axis. However, the result is not sinusoidal either. By the way, the length, x is a function of mass, m, time is a variable here.

Comment: Now this is exactly what one would expect if one hangs a bucket on a spring and increasingly fills it with water. The spring will continuously extend from the rest position proportional to the increasing mass. // What do you mean with "time is a variable here"? There is no time in your equation.

Comment: "Assume that the natural length of the bungee a player 30 meters" - I believe it should be the length of the cord.

Comment: @LutzLehmann You are right. "time is not a variable here", forgot a word, my bad.

Comment: Then what exactly is that equation supposed to model? And why do you expect any kind of dynamical changes (in a time progression) if the situation is static?

Comment: @LutzLehmann It is part of our homework. We are supposed to simulate the relation of the bungee cord length and the body weight. The task is to obtain the max body weight under a safe condition.

Comment: Yes, that indeed is quite a sensible task. But that is not what your simulation describes. The mass is constant during the time simulation, and you want the first maximum to be still "above ground" (at some point it is quite irritating to have the downward direction as positive, you also might have some mix up as `x<0`, `b=-k`, should be the stretched condition, not the loose one, where `b=0`). This means you have to compare several simulations for different weights, but during each simulation the weight of the jumper does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the length coordinate `x` to point upwards, the cord without jumper being at rest at position 0 so that for `x<0` the cord behaves like a spring. Then also gravity points downwards. The modified ODE function for this is

```
def dx_dt(x, t, m):
    acc = -g-a1/m*x[1]-a2/m*np.abs(x[1])*x[1]
    if x[0] < 0: acc -= k/m*x[0]
    return [x[1], acc]
```

Plotting for 3 different masses

```
for i,ini in enumerate(init):
    for m in masses: 
        xs = odeint(dx_dt, ini, t, args=(m,))
        ax[i].plot(t, xs[:, 0], label="m=%.2f"%m)
```

gives then the picture

[image]

If, as example, the ground level in the first situation is at `-80m`, giving a total height of `110m` then the mass of the jumper has to be less than 90kg. For more precise statements use inter- and extrapolation or a numerical solver to find the first time where `x'(t)=0` and the critical mass where `x(t)=ground` at that time.

It appears clear that in no case the jumper does re-enter the "free-fall" phase `x>0`.

Comment: You are so nice. Your answer is much more reasonable. I am aware that I was stuck in the example codes for the phase portraits, but the task is for another problem. The body weight is constant during the process, what I need to deal with is the "DYNAMIC" part which involves time. Again, thank you very much.